# multiprocessing slows down my code instead of speeding it up

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I've successfully used `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` in many codes to speed up computation time of loops. However I've encountered a problem that I can't figure out, where the more threads I add, the slower the code runs. This is all in python 2.7, running on an 8-core windoze box.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool 
from datetime import datetime
global X

pool=Pool(processes=1)

def foo(iy):
    global X
    x=X[iy]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x[i])):
            _=np.correlate(x[i,j],[1,1,1],mode='same')
    return None

t=datetime.now()
X=np.random.rand(11,11,512,512)
_=pool.map(foo,range(11))
print((datetime.now()-t).total_seconds())
```

with `processes=1`, this runs in 0.7 sec. That increases to 1 sec with `processes=2`, and 2.3 sec if `processes=4`. The same problem happens if I rewrite the code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool 
from datetime import datetime

pool=Pool(processes=1)

def foo(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x[i])):
            _=np.correlate(x[i,j],[1,1,1],mode='same')
    return None

t=datetime.now()
X=np.random.rand(11,11,512,512)
_=pool.map(lambda z:foo(X[z]),range(11))
print((datetime.now()-t).total_seconds())
```

I have a *lot* of looping to do, and really want/need the speedup from splitting those over multiple cores. Anyone have a thought on why multiprocessing is slowing me down instead, and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just testing with a limited dataset against the overhead of starting a new process? Maybe test it with a heavier dataset?

Answer (score 3):

While `np.correlate()` can (and in your case probably does) [release the GIL](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/710be5b4c61aded0d92a057bf488d71af86869f1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1211), I think your data is too small to produce any benefit.  That is, your Python code (the loops) is contending for the GIL, along with the "prologue" and "epilogue" parts of `np.correlate()` (which do hold the GIL).

You have a few options to improve your parallelism:

1. Implement your entire computation using `numba.jit(nogil=True)`.  But only a subset of NumPy is available there, and I don't think that includes `np.correlate()`.
2. Implement your computation using some other language such as Cython or C, and release the GIL while computing.
3. Switch from `multiprocessing.dummy` (which uses threads) to `multiprocessing` (which uses processes, so there's no contention for the GIL).
4. Use larger data in each call to `np.correlate()`.

Comment: Is the GIL still an issue for multiprocessing (as opposed to multithreading)? Doesn't each Python process have its own memory space and GIL?

Comment: @jmd_dk: Yes, as  I mentioned in point 3, multiprocessing solves the issue, and yes, each process has its own GIL.

Comment: Ah, `multiprocessing.dummy` doesn't actually use multiprocessing. Gotcha!